# Unity Rotation Issue - Character Feet look towards movement direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-development, quaternions

My question seems simple but I am also very simple and cannot figure this out. The thing is, I´ve got an IK system for the Character's legs. I need the character's feet to "look" in the movement direction.

If I do this: `rightLegCurrentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-transform.up);` 
The Character´s feet "look" flat down, just as I want, however, if I use the movement direction and do anything but fall down (Since that gives me the same value as -transform.up) the feet´s rotation completely goes wild and makes no sense.

Not sure if I´m explaining myself but essentially what I need is the player's feet to lay flat towards the given direction, kind of like this.
[image: Artistic Rendition]

Please let me know if I don´t make sense, quaternions are a real pain and I hardly understand what I´m doing. I am in dire need of help.